# Batch script interpreting content inside comment?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I run the following batch script:

```
@echo off
REM %~ will strip surrounding quotes if any

echo HERE
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\>test.cmd
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~ will strip surrounding quotes if any

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
```

Same effect if `REM` is changed to `::`.

Seems like the parser is ignoring the comment indicator and parsing the `%~`.  If I put a space between the `%` and `~` then it works fine.

Windows 7 Enterprise (have not checked any other versions).

Seems like a bug to me, but am I missing something?

Comment: I think that happens in an early parsing phase, for details see [how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%`-expansion, hence expanding normal environment variables (like `%VAR%`) as well as command line arguments (like `%0`), is the very first step after having read a line, therefore it happens even before the `rem` command is recognised. Thus you need to avoid the `%~` (by writing `rem % + ~ ...`, for instance).

Given that the [command extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled, which is the default anyway, `%~` is recognised as invalid argument syntax (the `~` is expected to be followed by a decimal digit denoting the argument position or by a valid modifier like `f`, `d`, `p`, `n`, `x`, etc.; see [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)) and results in a fatal error, meaning that an error message is thrown and batch file processing is aborted (the [`%ErrorLevel%`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) is not set though).

The same effect comes up when you try to do [sub-string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) but specifying an empty search string (like `%VAR:=replace%` or `%VAR:*=replace%`, given that `VAR` is defined), also with command extensions enabled.

See also this thread: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is clearly covered in quite a few docs that cmd will interpret the arguments before comments, see the example in @LotPings comment as well as @aschiphl's post. That being said, you can momentarily `disableextensions` and then turn it back on when needed. The below example shows how disabling it will allow you to use it in the `REM` comment and then enabled again after to show allow extensions:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableextensions
REM %~ will strip surrounding quotes if any"
endlocal
echo my batch file is %~0
```

Comment: Instead of `setlocal enableextensions` I would use `endlocal` to return to the former state (default) and to the former environment, thus having the same state as in the original code...

Comment: @aschipfl true yes, I think I just wanted to demonstrate enable and disable, but will change.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround idea!  Considering the extra lines to work around this, I simply used a valid expression there:  %~1.